# How to run ttest in SAS with selected groups as data set?

Tags: sas

I have a group of numbers, each labeled by a group letter, like

```
 Group | x | y
 A      135 12
 B      281 32
 C      221 2
 A      201 4 
 B      294  4
 C      950 ... etc
```

I am trying to run ttest on it, but ONLY on groups with prefix A  or C

I cannot use "data = " statement. 
So far I have

```
proc ttest where group = 'A', 'C'
   var x y;
run;
```

But this doesnt work. Any help?

Comment: You might be missing a semicolon `;` `proc ttest; where group = 'A', 'C'   var x y; run;`

Comment: how would i do that exactly? anywhere I can find a syntax sample?

Comment: So, `proc ttest data=dataname;where Group="A" OR Group="C"; var x y;run;` should work

Comment: Thank you! If you want to put it as answer so I could mark it

Comment: Also FYI this tests against null hypothesis of Ho=0 for each variable in the var statement.

Comment: @Reeza yeah the requirement is I cannot use "data="

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
proc ttest data=dataname;
where Group="A" OR Group="C"; 
var x y;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR but then you need to list the variable each time:

```
Where Group = 'A' OR Group = 'B';
```

Or you can use IN

```
Where Group in ('A', 'B');
```

Here's a worked example. Check the results of the check_where table. And look at the different results for the t-test, specifically the different p-values and N to show that you're using different data. Good Luck.

```
 data have;
 input Group $ x y;
 cards;
 A      135 12
 B      281 32
 C      221 2
 A      201 4 
 B      294 4
 C      950 8
 ;
 run;

 data check_where;
 set have;
 where group='A' or 'C';
 run;

proc ttest data=have; 
   where group = 'A' or 'C'; 
   var x y; 
run;

proc ttest data=have;
where group in ('A', 'B');
var x y;
run;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
proc ttest; 
   where group = 'A' or 'C'; 
   var x y; 
run;
```

Comment: That code is not correct, OR cannot be used that way. Use IN as I indicated in my comments.

Comment: This code is tested and working. I don't know why you have to dictate everything.

Comment: Test it again, you're wrong. The where condition in your code does not filter out A/C records. If thats not what you wanted then my apologies. But I'd bet money that I'm correct.

Comment: This is what happens when I use IN:  69         where group = 'a' in 'c';
                              __
                              22
                              76
 ERROR: Syntax error while parsing WHERE clause.
 ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, !, !!, &, *, **, +, -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, AND, EQ, GE, GT, LE, 
               LT, NE, NOT, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.  
 ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Comment: where is my money? :)

Comment: That's not the code I typed above, copy and paste if you need to.

Comment: if you are talking about: proc ttest;
where Group in ('A' 'C') ;
var x y;
run;    This one will void proc ttest command and will not output the ttest result.

Comment: You are doing something seriously wrong. Most likely since you're missing the data= statement :)

Comment: like I said the problem requirement is I am NOT allowed to use "data=".

Comment: And that's an example of why that requirement makes no sense. Anyways use it for testing and then remove it for your assignment. And test it again.

Comment: so, figure it out?